# Eclipse errors in comment

Tags: java, eclipse

Using Eclipse  I comment  out  errors  as temporary solution.
Every once and a while  these errors  remain  sticky (no way to get the errors away  even when code is removed by commenting (comment color confirms the comment)
    Save/clean/rebuild/restart of eclipse ...  nothing helps any more but a painstaking recreation of the project file by file ....   can anyone give me a tip ?
The error text is  often  removed module can not be resolved, variable can not be resolved 
this as only error  where the use of the variable  is completely removed!

I've the most recent eclipse version but had it with previous versions as well

Thanks in advance,  This can save me  day's of useless work.

Comment: Could you post some code (or screenshot) and tell which version do you have? When I comment code the only mar ks that remain are those of the ortography corrector.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I think I heard such issues are connected with incremental compilation - eclipse feature. Check this to disable it: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/221797/

Answer (score 3):

Please try this: 
What I usually do is I cut the entire document/file and paste it.
I am using Helios Service Release 1

```
Ctrl+A, Ctrl+C and then Ctrl+V.
```

It fixes the problem for me. I hope it does the same for you.
Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Just go to the problems list where the error/problem is listed and delete the entry, then it should also disappear from the editor.

Answer (score 1):

**-** Go to the Problems Tab at the bottom of the IDE.

**-** Remove all the Error and Warning Entries.

**-** At last Clean the Project.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking right mouse button and select the option "spelling check". I´ve realised I have this errors when I write comments in my native lenguage, not in english.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error. The problem in my case was disabled autobuild in Eclipse. (**Project > Build Automatically**)

Answer (score 0):

click on the comment being where error is shown. Click on "Disable spell check"

Comment: Please consider step by step instruction or screenshots as answer.

Comment: ...and preferably the former more than the latter.